# Apache will not show index pages

Tags: apache-http-server, php, debian-wheezy

I have just set up my brand new raspberry pi with Rasbian-Wheezy and a clean install of apache and php.

I got the "it works" page, and then put my website in place and everything was working, but at some point whilst I was fixing some php errors the index stopped working.  If I go to `http://my-pi/index.php` I see the page, but if I instead go to `http://my-pi/` I get an error page, and the apache error log says `client denied by server configuration: /var/www/www/.php`.

I have tried adding `DirectoryIndex index.php` to the `.htaccess` file but the problem is still there.  I have also tried enabling and disabling the viewing of the directory listing when there is no index page and still nothing.  Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: We don't consider the RPi to be a server within the meaning of Server Fault. The enthusiast nature of the device makes it a better fit for [su] or [unix.se].

Comment: The question is not about the pi itself, but the apache server software that's installed.  I was under the impression that this would be the same as an apache installation on any other linux machine, and therefore within the scope of this site.

Comment: We don't care. If it were about the Pi the [raspberrypi.se] would be the correct place for this question. Please read [about] to familiarise yourself with our scope and topicality. Please also read http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5586/are-raspberrypis-ever-on-topic-for-serverfault where we discussed the topicality of RPi and decided that we do not want questions regarding them. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: If you're referring to the thing about questions needing to be about systems used for professional uses, and how a raspberry pi couldn't possibly be used for this, your wrong.  I will be using the pi to host my website which will host my portfolio and documentation for software I have created, which I see as a professional use of a system.  Also, as I mentioned, the problem is with something in the apache server or something related to it, not with the fact that it's running on a pi.